# Pandas function to make sequential based on label

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a data which I want to find the sequence for a certain event based on the login_status and another category value.

```
user_id     content_id       login_status         
    1            2            not login               
    1            3            not login               
    1            4            login                   
    2            2            login                   
    2            3            login
```

and i want to make sequence column like this

```
user_id     content_id       login_status         sequence
    1            2            not login               1
    1            3            not login               1
    1            4            login                   2
    2            2            login                   1
    2            3            login                   1
```

so i want to make a sequence when user watch when user login the sequence is 2

this is the code i've tried

```
   df1['Seq'] = df1.groupby((df1[['user_id', 'login_status']] != df1[['user_id', 'login_status']].shift(1)).any(axis=1).cumsum()).cumcount() + 1
```

but the squance sum when login status not change

how to solve this issue

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: the sequence if users login from not login activity the squance is 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want something like this which uses the *shift-cumsum pattern*:

```
df.assign(
    sequence=df.groupby(['user_id'], sort=False)
               .apply(lambda x: (x['login_status'] != x['login_status'].shift()).cumsum())
               .values
)
```

This will increment the sequence for each `user_id` whenever the `login_status` changes.

Comment: ahh I see, you separate the process into two processes, any thanks, the problem is solved